# Encapsulating an Angular app inside a web component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli, web-component, angular6

I have a simple angular-cli app consisting of only one component (app.component). I have created one custom build-script.js which I use to merge all the files (.js and .css) created using ng build --prod. So I get only two files in my dist folder (Index.html and ng-app.js).

I have another static website with just two files index.html and script.js. Now I want to load my compiled Angular app as a widget inside this static app. I am trying to encapsulate the Angular app inside web component (shadow dom) so that it will not mess with the parent static app and can be loaded as a widget.

**static app index.html:**

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Widget App</title>
</head>

<body>

    <!-- custom web component Widget holding angular app -->
    <ng-widget></ng-widget>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

**script.js:**

```
window.customElements.define('ng-widget', class extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
            super();
            var shadowRoot = this.attachShadow({
                mode: 'open'
            });
            shadowRoot.innerHTML =
                `
                <!doctype html>
                <html lang="en">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8">
                        <title>NgWidget</title>
                        <base href="/">

                        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <app-root></app-root>

                        <!-- The ng-app.js is not getting download since it is inside shadow dom -->
                        <script type="text/javascript" src="./ng-app.js"></script>

                    </body>

                    </html>

` } });
```

Now since the link to **ng-app.js** is inside shadow dom, it is not getting downloaded and my Angular app is not bootstraping.

What is the best way to render a Angular app as a widget inside a static website?

Comment: I really don't see why would you want to encapsulate an angular app inside a webcomponent but anyway, you might want to take a look to angular elements to see if you can create your angular components as web components. https://angular.io/guide/elements

Comment: I see components a small disconnected things that can be glued together with other code. Trying to make the entire app as a single component seems like code-smell to me.